# ASP.NET vnext and open database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

is there some possibility to work with an open database like mysql, mariadb or other and ASP.NET vNext?

Perhaps a beta driver or something like that?

Comment: Why would you not be able to use mysql with _any_ version of ASP.NET?

Answer (score 6):

For ASP.NET vNext you can choose to target the full .NET Framework or a slimmed down, bin-deployable, cross platform, Core framework.

If you target the full .NET Framework then you get all the data access options you had before. If you target the CoreCLR then you can use the new version of Entity Framework (EF7). Currently we have the following providers available on CoreCLR; SQL Server, SQLite, and an in memory provider for testing. Of course, more providers will become available as we work towards RTM.

In addition to EF7, there are also the corresponding provider specific SDKs that EF is building on top of, and these can be used in application code as well (e.g. there is an implementation of SqlClient that can be used to access a SQL Server database).

You can read more about our plans for EF7 here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/05/19/ef7-new-platforms-new-data-stores.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if you are using the CoreCLR (the trimmed down version) or the Desktop profiles. In the Desktop profile you have everything you have in .NET available and you can add your own open source libraries (via Nuget).

**Just open up your project.json and add the needed dependencies.**

Anyway you should not be dealing with low level ADO.NET, you can use Entity Framework, or Massive or nHibernate, or whatever, to abstract away the specific database your project is using now, as it is bound to change or multiply during the project lifetime...

Comment: Hey thx for your great comment. But I want to use the CoreCLR to  release the code later on a linux machiene.

Comment: @Monoman well I'm a new guy anyway how to use entity framework in vnext mvc, I found no option in add new item and there is any way to use odata.

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to use anything ADO.Net related with ASP.Net vNext - it is, after all, still .Net!

Comment: Ah ok but can use the standart classes of Ado (Sqlcommand) and so on to talk with the mysql server?

Comment: If you add the MySQL ADO.Net drivers, sure!

Comment: But they wont be run later on a linux machiene right? :-)

Comment: Why wouldn't they?  http://www.mono-project.com/Database_Access points to a MySQL ADO.Net adapter which will work under all CLR platforms as its fully managed.

Comment: As far as I have been able to determine, the CoreCLR doesn't support ADO.Net (only System.Data.Common), so you won't be able to use any providers for mysql or postgresql. Will this change in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but only if you use full .net profile (on windows it will be .net framework and on linux - mono). NHibernate working well on mono, so you can eventually use mysql, postgresql and other databases in you APS.NET 5 vNext application. Here is complete example of application with [NHibernate and PostgreSQL on Ubuntu server](http://druss.co/2015/04/vnext-use-postgresql-fluent-nhibernate-from-asp-net-5-dnx-on-ubuntu/).